# Facebook ASP.NET MVC from template not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, visual-studio-2013

I create project from template(ASP.NET MVC -> Facebook).

And receive error

> Could not convert string to integer: public_profile. Path 'data[0].permission', line 1, position 39.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Could not convert string to integer: public_profile. Path 'data[0].permission', line 1, position 39.

If i change [FacebookAuthorize("public_profile","email")] to [FacebookAuthorize()], i not recieve error, but can't recieve email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with the .NET SDK. Facebook recently changed their API

https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/issues/293

Answer (score 3):

Try to remove the "email" and "userPhotos" from [FacebookAuthorize("email", "user_photos")].

If you actually need permissions, see my thoughts and workaround [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/miziel/2014/06/14/working-around-facebooksdk-net-permissions-bug-facebookauthorize-attribute/)

Answer (score 0):

Change the below in HomeController from 
 [FacebookAuthorize("email", "user_photos")]
to 
 [FacebookAuthorize]