# Exception in ASP.NET MVC Facebook template

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to Facebook app development and i'm using dot net for this. 
But I'm facing the following Exception:

```
[JsonReaderException: Could not convert string to integer: public_profile. Path 'data[0].permission', line 1, position 39.]
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAsInt32Internal() +586
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsInt32() +5
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter) +129
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateDictionary(IWrappedDictionary wrappedDictionary, JsonReader reader, JsonDictionaryContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id) +825
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) +515
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) +91
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IWrappedCollection wrappedList, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id) +630
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id) +196
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) +118
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target) +206
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id) +1349
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) +261
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) +91
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent) +426
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) +413
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings) +108
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type) +7
   Facebook.FacebookClient.ProcessResponse(HttpHelper httpHelper, String responseString, Type resultType, Boolean containsEtag, IList`1 batchEtags) +1189
   Facebook.FacebookClient.Api(HttpMethod httpMethod, String path, Object parameters, Type resultType) +737
   Facebook.FacebookClient.Get(String path, Object parameters, Type resultType) +19
   Facebook.FacebookClient.Get(String path, Object parameters) +71
   Facebook.FacebookClient.Get(String path) +62
   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Facebook.Client.FacebookClientExtensions.GetCurrentUserPermissions(FacebookClient client) +32
   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Facebook.Providers.DefaultFacebookPermissionService.GetUserPermissions(String userId, String accessToken) +49
   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Facebook.Authorization.FacebookAuthorizeFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) +2946
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +445
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +129
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +302
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +129
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +338
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +129
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +316
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +71
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +129
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +251
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

I've already Googled it first and i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23538682/facebook-asp-net-mvc-from-template-not-work), but this also does not worked for me. Here is my code for HomeController:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Facebook;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Facebook.Client;
using FacebookBirthdayApp.Models;

namespace FacebookBirthdayApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [FacebookAuthorize("email", "user_photos")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index(FacebookContext context)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await context.Client.GetCurrentUserAsync<MyAppUser>();
                return View(user);
            }

            return View("Error");
        }

        // This action will handle the redirects from FacebookAuthorizeFilter when 
        // the app doesn't have all the required permissions specified in the FacebookAuthorizeAttribute.
        // The path to this action is defined under appSettings (in Web.config) with the key 'Facebook:AuthorizationRedirectPath'.
        public ActionResult Permissions(FacebookRedirectContext context)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(context);
            }

            return View("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried removing the email and user_photos from the parameters but this also did not worked.

Please suggest me what to do?

Comment: The problem is with JSON deserialization. Can you provide JSON sample that you get and your `MyAppUser` class?

Comment: No experience with .Net SDK, but this might be due to the SDK not handling new response formats from Facebook API. For instance, [`GET /me/permissions` format has changed from v1.0 -> v2.x](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api). So if the SDK is expecting the old format, it's probably going to break if the API returned the new format.